# Ant build.xml execution in Linux Box

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, ant

I'm trying to execute selenium test scripts (Ant build.xml) in linux box, I used below command line

```
ant -buildfile build.xml
```

I got below failure exception

```
sai@ip-10-3-59-39:~/WEB_Prod$ ant –buildfile build.xml
Buildfile: /home/sai/WEB_Prod/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "–buildfile" does not exist in the project "Test".
```

Request you to help me with some inputs to resolve the issue.

Comment: Change `–buildfile` to `-buildfile`. You're using an ['EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) character, and it has to be a ['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) character.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I got below error after making some changes

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
     [java] Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Comment: [java] System info: host: 'ip-10-3-59-39', ip: '10.3.59.39', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-1044-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
     [java] Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
     [java] remote stacktrace: #0 0x55f329ee9959 <unknown>

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question, so delete this question and create a new one,

Comment: If you're just running a target in build.xml, you don't need to specify your build file. Just run `ant`. And even when you do need to specify one, you can use `-f` as shorthand for `--buildfile`.